# Using DataFrame to get matrix of identifiers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am an R user who is new to python. I have some data

```
dat1=DataFrame({'user_id':['a1','a1','a4','a3','a1','a15', 'a8', 'a15'      ,'a1', 'a5'],
 'Visits':[1,4,2,1,3,1,1,8,1,9],'cell': [14,21,14,14,19,10,18,17,10,11], 
 'date': ['2011-01-05', '2011-01-05', '2011-01-12', '2011-01-12', '2011-01-12',   '2011-01-12', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-19', '2011-01-19', '2011-01-19' ] })




 dat1['date']=pd.to_datetime(dat1['date'])

 dat2=dat1.sort_index(by='date')
```

This gives me a DataFrame of the form

```
Visits  cell     date     user_id
   1    18   2011-01-02      a8
   1    14   2011-01-05      a1
   4    21   2011-01-05      a1
   2    14   2011-01-12      a4
   1    14   2011-01-12      a3
   3    19   2011-01-12      a1
   1    10   2011-01-12     a15
   8    17   2011-01-19     a15
   1    10   2011-01-19      a1
   9    11   2011-01-19      a5
```

I want to create a DataFrame such that each column is identified with a unique user_id and each row is a unique date. Each cell contains a 
0 or 1 depending on whether the user_id and the date share a row in the original DataFrame. In R

I would use sapply and a user defined function for this operation, but in Python I am struggling to find a solution.

With my array of user_ids denoted as

```
user_names= dat2['user_id'].unique()
```

My final DataFrame should be of the form

```
a8 a1 a4 a3 a15 a5
1  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0  0
0  1  1  1  1  0
0  1  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `get_dummies` function to your advantage here:

```
users = data.set_index('date')['user_id']
visits = pd.get_dummies(users)
```

This gives us a dataframe which uses "one-hot" encoding to denote whether a user visited on the date:

```
            a1  a15  a3  a4  a5  a8
date                               
2011-01-02   0    0   0   0   0   1
2011-01-05   1    0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-05   1    0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-12   0    0   0   1   0   0
2011-01-12   0    0   1   0   0   0
2011-01-12   1    0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-12   0    1   0   0   0   0
2011-01-19   0    1   0   0   0   0
2011-01-19   1    0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-19   0    0   0   0   1   0
```

But the dates are repeated. We therefore group by the date index and aggregate, asking if the user visited on *any* of the entries for that date:

```
visits.groupby(visits.index).any().astype(int)
```

which gives:

```
            a1  a15  a3  a4  a5  a8
date                               
2011-01-02   0    0   0   0   0   1
2011-01-05   1    0   0   0   0   0
2011-01-12   1    1   1   1   0   0
2011-01-19   1    1   0   0   1   0
```